# How can I program a mysql database to run an action after some time?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to write some code to program my mysql database to execute an update table action after some time passed. I think that this can be done with triggers but cant find a solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can run triggers on a particular time of the day (i.e every hour) or an event.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I can use scheduled events instead of triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, you can use scheduled events instead of triggers, but if you have a file.php (or can creat it), you can use **Cron Jobs**. I usually use cron job. Working with it is simple, practical and it high performance. use it ..